# Custom query in Spring Data Neo4j not retrieving relationships

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

So for a few complex operations, I am using custom Cypher queries using the @Query annotation on my custom finder methods in my graph repositories. However, while it retrieves the node, it does not retrieve its direct relationships (i.e. only 1 level).

```
@Query("match (node:T) return node Order by node.requestedAt Desc LIMIT 100")
List<T> last100T();

@Query("match (node:T) where node.status = \"REQUESTED\" and  timestamp() - node.requestedAt >= 60000 return node")
List<Transit> findUnmatchedAndExpiredT();
```

I am using them like this - (code is in groovy):

```
 def nodes = TRepository.findUnmatchedAndExpiredT()
    nodes.forEach({
        node ->
            node.status = TStatus.DECLINED
            node.neighbourA.status = NeighbourAStatus.BARRED
            def neighbourBQueue = client.queue(node.neighbourB.username)
            neighbourBQueue.push(mapper.writeValueAsString(node))

    TRepository.save(node)
})
```

They are related like so:

```
    @NodeEntity
class T{

    public T(){
    }

    @GraphId
    Long id

    @Relationship(type = "REQUESTED_BY", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    NeighbourB neighbourB

    @Relationship(type = "SERVICED_BY", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    NeighbourA neighbourA
}
```

Both Neighbours A and B are null when the relationships do exist. What do? I'm using Spring boot 1.2.7.RELEASE with spring-data-neo4j:4.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom queries (@Query) do not support a depth parameter and they map exactly what the query returns. If you're returning a single node, it'll map that single node. The query is not modified at runtime to include extra relationships.

You can return the node ID instead and then `load` it with the default depth (1), or a custom depth.

In a future release, SDN 4 will be able to map multiple entities returned in custom queries to domain entities.

Comment: Here are the related issues to this problem: [DATAGRAPH-782](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-782), [DATAGRAPH-771](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-771) and [DATAGRAPH-700](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-700). Also take a look at [this article](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/06/mapping-query-entities-sdn.html) about the use of custom queries.

Comment: "In a future release" - is this feature still in the future 2 years later? An entity w/o relationships is almost useless.

Comment: SDN 4 already maps entities returned in custom queries to domain entities.

Comment: I'm using SDN 5 and it does not return relationships. Do I need to do something special?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, it seems to work for depth 1. The result nodes contain a non-`null` reference to relationship objects. But it's important that you return all 3 results: Node (`n`), relationship type (`r`), relationship node (`u`), e. g.:

```
@Query("MATCH(n:MyEntity) MATCH (n)-[r:MY_REL_TYPE]-(u) RETURN n, r, u LIMIT {0}")
List<MyEntity> getAll(int limit);
```